# Shirk in the mind

Tags: shirk

If you commit shirk in your mind but you believe in your faith and in Allah and you only follow Allah will you be held accountable for those thoughts

In my case I keep having annoying thoughts that say the name Jesus. But I know it’s wrong to say this because it’s shirk and I know only Catholics and christans say this because they take Jesus as their lord but I don’t and I only believe in Allah as my lord

Comment: As I mentioned in [the answer to your other question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/61268/39316), the word "Jesus" in and of itself is not shirk; it's simply the name of the messenger of Allah (Jesus = Isa = Iesa). Even saying it out loud is okay. It only depends on how you use the word. For example, there's absolutely nothing wrong with saying _"Jesus was a messenger of Allah"_ or _"Jesus, peace be upon him"_. However, saying _"Jesus!"_ or _"Oh, Jesus!"_ as a call for help (similar to how Christians say it) is not right and might lead to shirk (depending on the intent)...

Comment: I think that's not what you're doing though so it's totally fine to use the word "Jesus" in the right context. It's used several times in translations of the Quran as I said in the other post.

Comment: انما الاعمال بالنیات. Besides using a prophet’s name is not shirk

Answer (score 0):

Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدُ بْنُ مَنْصُورٍ، وَقُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، وَمُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عُبَيْدٍ الْغُبَرِيُّ، - وَاللَّفْظُ لِسَعِيدٍ - قَالُوا حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَوَانَةَ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ، عَنْ زُرَارَةَ بْنِ أَوْفَى، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏

‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ تَجَاوَزَ لأُمَّتِي مَا حَدَّثَتْ بِهِ أَنْفُسَهَا مَا لَمْ يَتَكَلَّمُوا أَوْ يَعْمَلُوا بِهِ ‏"

‏ ‏‏

It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) observed:

Verily Allah forgave my people the evil promptings which arise within their hearts as long as they did not speak about them or did not act upon them.

Sahih Muslim 127 a
In-book : Book 1, Hadith 238
USC-MSA web (English) : Book 1, Hadith 230  (deprecated)
Sahih Muslim

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is the second most mentioned prophet in the Qu'ran after the Prophet Mohammed; it's not a sign of shirk. In fact, Ibn Arabi said in his *Bezels of Wisdom* that the *awliya* followed one of the prophets, in that they have a special relationship to them. In fact, each of the chapters is named after a prophet mentioned in the Qu'ran. This is in no way shirk.

Comment: FWIW I think the most discussed in Qur'an is Moses and Bani Israel. I searched quran.com for موسی and found 131 instances, for عیسی it was just 45 and for محمد its 66, though you could argue that Prophet Mohammad was mentioned with different names, but I still think given the sheer number of verses about Bani Israel, Prophet Moses has had more mentions...

Comment: @Honey: I just checked and that matches. I don't recall where I read that Jesus was the second most mentioned - he must have confused this with his importance.