# Is this a shirk

Tags: shirk

Is saying Jesus Christ in a sentence shirk? Example. Saying “Jesus Christ is not my lord.” Because I said the following sentence stated above and now I fear I might’ve committed shirk as only Catholics and christans say it

Answer (score 2):

I believe the word in and of itself is not shirk; it just depends on how you use it. So, we have two words here:

- **"Jesus"**: That's just the name of the Messenger of Allah. There's nothing wrong with it.
- **"Christ"**: This has the same meaning as the word ["Messiah"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messiah) <sup>(1)</sup> which is mentioned several time in the Quran.

So, I don't think there's a problem with saying *"Jesus Christ is not my lord"*, considering that it has the same meaning as *"The Messiah, Jesus/Isa is not my lord"* and you can find versus in the Quran with similar meaning. For example:

> ..The Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, was but a messenger of Allah...
>
> [Surat An-Nisa [4:171](https://quran.com/4/171)]

**However,** the same words could be used in a way that might lead to shirk. For example, using it in the same way that Christians use it to express some emotions (e.g., saying "[Oh,] Jesus Christ!") which might imply a call for help (i.e., thinking of Jesus as God).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>[This is a clip](https://youtu.be/cjTqZOI-QT8?t=107) in which, [Ahmed Deedat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmed_Deedat) uses both words ("Messiah" and "Christ") and confirms that one is translated to the other.</sub>